# i want to enter data in a complete column without according to row data

Tags: android-sqlite

i'm using sq lite database in android 
i already have data in two columns i want to change data in column 2 without condition of where
where ever i searched where condition is used 
this is how i stored

```
public boolean updateData(String name, String pass){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(col2,pass);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues, col1+" =?", new String[]{name});
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `null` for the 3d and 4th arguments:

```
public boolean updateData(String pass) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(col2, pass);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, null, null);
    db.close();
    return true;
}
```

I guess you don't need the parameter `name` since there is no `WHERE` clause, so I removed it.

Comment: So it will change the existing value from the top to bottom in all rows? Instead we update that one by one

Comment: Exactly, see this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)